# How many equations do we have in the condition $F_1(x)=F_2(x)=F_3(x)=F_4(x)$?

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

I have these four functions

$$ F_1(x)=a e^{2 i x}+b e^{-2 i x} \\ F_2(x)=c e^{2 i x}+d e^{-2 i x} \\ F_3(x)=j e^{2 i x}+f e^{-2 i x} \\ F_4(x)=g e^{2 i x}+h e^{-2 i x}  $$

which satisfy this condition

$$F_1(0)=F_2(0)=F_3(0)=F_4(0),\qquad\qquad (1)$$
which is simplified to

$$a+b=c+d=f+j=g+h \qquad\qquad (2)$$

**QUESTION**

If I want to consider condition $(1)$ or $(2)$ as a system of equations, how many equations do we have here?

Answer (score 1):

You have many equations, but you only have three *independent* equations.

Once you state

- $a+b=c+d$
- $c+d=e+f$
- $e+f=g+h$

then you have captured all the information in your statement

- $a+b=c+d=e+f=g+h$

What's more, you *need* all three of those equations to fully capture it all.

A more rigorous way to approach this would be to write down literally all possible equalities:

- $a+b=c+d$
- $a+b=e+f$
- $a+b=g+h$
- $c+d=e+f$
- $c+d=g+h$
- $e+f=g+h$

convert them to matrix form:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&-1&-1&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&0&-1&-1&0&0\\
1&1&0&0&0&0&-1&-1\\
0&0&1&1&-1&-1&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&0&0&-1&-1\\
0&0&0&0&1&1&-1&-1\\
\end{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$$

and then prove that the big matrix has rank 3 (eg, by reducing it to row-echelon form), or by finding a basis for its kernel and using the rank-nullity theorem)

However, it seems unlikely this more formal approach is called for in your situation, whatever it is.